# 3-phase system with 3 loads instead of 2?

Tags: three-phase, delta

[image]

Hello,

Most examples on the internet and in my text books contain 1 load with 1 source. I have yet to come across an example with 3 loads. Is there a way of combining the loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the line voltage so you can calculate the phase voltage and work out what line current the star load is taking per phase. You know what the delta load is so you can calculate the line current for it.

Add the two together to get total line current of the first two loads then subtract that from the total supply line current to get the current taken by the unknown load. The current that remains and the phase voltage define the impedance of the unknown load.

Comment: how would one draw this?

Comment: @Rene I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean how to draw a circuit or how to draw a delta or star load or how to draw several star and delta loads connected to a 3 phase supply or.....?

Comment: Sorry wasnt very clear on that.. I meant how to draw the circuit in the question. I dont understand how it would look. Maybe if I can wrap my head around that I'll be able to get my thoughts together

Comment: The star load is just resistors (hence the angle of 0 degrees) and the delta load is capacitors hence the +90 degrees.

Comment: So I just draw resistors and capacitors in series?

Comment: The loads are independent hence they connect to the supply independently so they cannot be in series. Draw a delta load of 3 capacitors connected to a 3 ph supply then, further along the page extend the 3 ph supply wires and draw a star load of 3 resistors. Post it somewhere and I'll check it and get you to add the third "unknown" load.